# Get first column in dataframe that exists from list of column names

Tags: pandas

Given a list of column names, only some or none exist in a dataframe, what's the least verbose way of getting the first existing column or `None`?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])

cols = ["d", "e", "c"]
```

This is fairly short but fails with `StopIteration` for no matching columns:

```py
col = next(filter(lambda c: c in df, cols))

df[col]
0    3
1    6
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with:

```py
col = next(filter(lambda c: c in df, cols), None)
```

Answer (score 3):

One idea:

```
col = next(iter(df.columns.intersection(cols, sort=False)), None)
```

Comment: This just occurred to me as well. Why the `sort=False`?

Comment: @Casimir - because `intersection` by default sorting, so should return wrong value if not sorted list or columns names

Comment: @jezrael i edited your code to pass sort=False to intersection instead of iter

Answer (score 2):

[@Learnings is a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275464/learning-is-a-mess) answered it beautifully and you should use that solution but here is another one line solution with walrus operator.

```
col = intersect[0] if (intersect:= [c for c in cols if c in df.columns]) else None
```